# AngularJS HTML5 mode routing with apache2 .htaccess

Tags: angularjs, apache2, html5mode

I am building angularjs project with PHP, MySQL, apache2 on Ubuntu system

Project structure
`var/www/html/demo/`

Demo folder is my project folder,
`demo=>js(All js file), index.php, addstudent.php file etc`

I am facing problem while refreshing the whole page and also using routing concept in AngularJS with html5Mode(true) but it doesn't working properly with .htaccess file.

The requested URL /demo/addstudent was not found on this server.

htacces code here

DirectoryIndex demo/index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /demo/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

In index.php added base ref is

Comment: there are lots of examples of htaccess needed on the web. Show what you have tried that isn't working

Comment: please update question itself with formatted code instead of putting it in comment blocks